# Imageview scaling keeping height fix and width variable

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make height of a imageview constant and based on aspect ratio width should vary. But I can see if I give width as wrap_content then height is less than fixed height because keeping aspect ratio, height corresponding to wrap_content width is less fixed height. I want width to adjust keeping height exact a fix value.

Comment: did you tried scaleType http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: yes all scaleTypes scales to min (height and width) or else they would not keep aspect ratio same. I want to keep same aspect ratio and scale according to one dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the [scaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) to MATRIX. And then you can manage the size by your self, it will not try to save aspect ratio

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/KyoSherlock/AspectRatioLayout

May be this is what you want. You can use AspectRatioImageView.

`<com.sherlock.aspectratio.AspectRatioImageView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        app:widthHeightRatio="2" >`